# Conditional Data.table aggregation to list column if all elements in id match

Tags: r, data.table

Heres the problem testing equality for each id

```
DTT<-data.table(id=rep(1:3,each=2), CHAR=c("A","B","A","B","A","C"), key="id")
   id CHAR
1:  1    A
2:  1    B
3:  2    A
4:  2    B
5:  3    A
6:  3    C
```

Because id 1,2 has the same values for all CHAR variables, it will be grouped like this

```
groupid  idlist
      1   1,2
      2   3
```

Is there also a way to group them if theyre close enough i.e. off by 1 value? It would look like this

```
groupid  idlist
      1   1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do a group by id' and `paste` the 'CHAR' elements, then in the second step, use the `paste`d elements as grouping column to convert the 'id' into a `list`

```
library(data.table)
 DTT[, paste(CHAR, collapse = ""),id][, .(idlist = list(id)), 
     .(groupid = match(V1, unique(V1)))]
```

-output

```
   groupid idlist
     <int> <list>
1:       1    1,2
2:       2      3
```

---

Or a similar option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DTT %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(groupid = str_c(CHAR, collapse = "")) %>% 
   group_by(groupid = match(groupid, unique(groupid))) %>% 
   summarise(idlist = list(id))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  groupid idlist   
    <int> <list>   
1       1 <int [2]>
2       2 <int [1]>
```

---

For the updated case, use a distance method to group the elements

```
DTT[, paste(CHAR, collapse = ""), id][,
   V1 := colSums(adist(V1) < max(nchar(V1)))][, 
   .(idlist = list(id)), .(groupid = match(V1, unique(V1)))]
   groupid idlist
     <int> <list>
1:       1  1,2,3
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Is there a way to specify a partial match?

Comment: For example if there was was partial match like off by one character it would be   groupid idlist   
    <int> <list>   
1       1 <int [3]>